# Adding a rolling average to pandas dataframes in a loop takes forever

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, large-data

I have a rather large dictionary of pandas dataframes. The keys are stock symbol, and each dataframe has 14 columns, containing stock market data. For example:

```
eodscreen['AAPL']
Out[35]: 
                 date   open    high      low  close     volume  ex-dividend  \
date                                                                           
2010-01-04 2010-01-04   5.82   5.980   5.8000   5.98   685500.0          0.0   
2010-01-05 2010-01-05   5.99   6.000   5.8300   5.93   419500.0          0.0 
...
...
```

I'm trying to add a ***new*** column for each stock called 'MA', containing the moving average of the 'close' column.

Here is my simple loop:

```
for k in eodscreen:
    eodscreen[k]['MA'] = eodscreen[k]['close'].rolling(window=5).mean()
```

This code takes about 3 minutes to run (on a few years old laptop, i7, 16GB RAM...).

I am getting the following warning, maybe it explains part of the problem?

```
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
> using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I don't have a good feel for what is a 'large' dictionary so maybe that is quite normal?

> Dictionary: 1600 keys each containing a dataframe.
>
> Each dataframe: 1 date column, 13 float64 columns, 1740 rows per
>   column.

If this is to be expected, could you please provide insight as to how such data should be loaded and accessed in a program? It is all stored in a ~400MB csv file and I load it all at the beginning of my program and organize everything in the dictionary. Would it be better to read only the data of 1 stock symbol, perform whatever math I want, re-write the file and so on, or I'm on the right track thinking I can do it all from memory (easier)!

Any comments / insights are highly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign on a slice of a slice that happens to be a view of another dataframe.  It happened because of how you created the dictionary in the first place.

Work around:

```
for k in eodscreen:
    eodscreen[k] = eodscreen[k].assign(MA=df['close'].rolling(window=5).mean())
```

The reason I'm suggesting this should work is that you are reassigning a copy of the dataframe with a new column to the dictionary key.

Comment: Wow that ran in like 5 sec. I don't really understand your explanation though - is my dictionary not what I think it is?

Comment: It is what you think it is.  Check the `is_copy` property of one of the dataframes.  It will come back as something strange like `<weak-reference>` or something.  This means that it is a copy of another dataframe and that is why you are getting the warning.  You may have assigned the values to each key from a panel like `eodscreen[k] = panel[k]`  and that would have assigned the slice of the panel, which is a dataframe, but because you used `panel[k]` instead of `panel.loc[k]` you get a copy instead of a fresh new dataframe.  Thai is what the warning was trying to tell you. use `panel.loc[k]`

Comment: hmmm so my dictionary came from a date screen I did on the 'original' one called 'eodall'.

`eodscreen = { k: eodall[k].ix[startdate:enddate] for k in eodall }`

So my 'eodscreen' dictionary is not a new dictionary, but pointing to the same data as eodall, only a subset of it?

Comment: The dictionary is new, the dataframes in it are copies.  Per the `SetWithCopyWarning` do this instead `eodscreen = { k: eodall.loc[k, startdate:enddate] for k in eodall }`

Comment: Interesting. The way you propose means that the data would be pretty much duplicated in memory. Would that be a bad thing to do?

Comment: That depends on a lot.  That sounds like a different question to me.